# 2D interpolation

Tags: math, code-challenge, test-battery, expression-building

Given required values for an expression with 2 variables, output a short expression which fulfill these values

## Input

You may take the input in any reasonable format, e.g. `f(x,y)=z`, `{(x, y): z}`, `[[[x,y],z]]`, but please write what format is your input is taken in

## Output

Your output needs the be a valid infix expression for two variables, and it has to output the correct value when rounding the output to three digits after the comma, but the current value isn't rounded during calculation. The following symbols/operators are allowed:

### symbols

```
x - the first input variables
y - the second input variables
pi - 3.1415 (4 digit precision)
e - 2.7182 (4 digit precision)
every possible numeric constant (1, 0.12, 42, 13.241)
```

### operators

```
+ sum of two values, in the format a+b
- difference of two values, in the format a-b
* multiplication of two values, in the format a*b
/ division of two values, in the format a/b
^ power of two values, in the format a^b
|| absolute value, in the format |a|
() parentheses, in the format (a)
floor the floor of a value, in the format floor(a)
ceil the ceil of a value, in the format ceil(a)
```

if I forgot anything that you think is important tell me in the comments please.

## Example Testcases

other expressions are okay if they result in the correct values

```
f(0.12, 0.423) = 3.142
f(0.89, 0.90) = 3.142
|
\/
pi (3.1415 gets rounded to 3 digits after the comma - 3.142)

f(0.12, 0.423) = 0.543
f(0.89,0.9)=1.79
|
\/
x+y
```

## Score

Your score is the average length of expression for the following input: https://pastebin.com/tfuBjpc6 , where each batch of inputs (a different function) is separated by a newline. You can transform the format to any format your program accept.

Good luck!

Comment: Since the score depends on the size of the expressions, I guess the program is supposed to be deterministic. Is that correct?

Comment: It doesn't have it be, it's goal is that the average expression length would be minimal.

Comment: You might want to specify a little bit better on what input values we should score our programs. Even if you set the seed to a specific value in your scorer program, that only works for Python programs. Different submissions will be scored differently from eachother.

Comment: the generate_expression code should call the program (i.e. by executing a shell command), but I think I should randomly generate expressions and then post there values in here and the average length of these would be counted

Comment: I edited it to include the test-battery tag, and a link to the list of tested values

Comment: could the answer be a more complex expression like `(x+y)^x`?

Comment: @Jonah yes, it can be any valid expression

Comment: @SurculoseSputum fixed, the file was duplicated with an incorrect version

Comment: Do all of the examples in the test battery have 5 contraints?

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter yes

Comment: @CommandMaster Great challenge, and the strict format for expression is great at allowing language neutrality. I just want to clarify one point - must the expression use both variables (meaning it must contain `x` and `y`)? The example shows otherwise. And if it is allowed to give `pi` as an answer for output `3.142`, can one give `0.123` when the output is `0.123` (since numeric constants are valid part of expression)?

Comment: yes, you can just use `pi` or `0.123`, the expression doesn't have to include both variables

Comment: @CommandMaster Would you mind sharing how is the input data generated?

Comment: I made a script to recursively choose random operations/consts

Comment: @CommandMaster What I meant was that *the answer can be simply the output* - `lambda x, y, z: str(z)`, which is the shortest in *most* cases (and a scan for all length `5` expressions would suffice to eliminate that too). I think it should be prohibited, so the answer actually has to look for some expression.

Answer (score 1):

## C++ (gcc), score: 39.2533

Interpolate `x`s or `y`s and `f`s with [lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
string ml(const string& a,const string& b) {
	if(a.size()<b.size()) return a;
	return b;
};
string prt(double x,int g,int d=0) {
	char buf[100],buf2[100];
	sprintf(buf,"%%+.%dlf",g);
	sprintf(buf2,buf,x);
	string s=buf2;
	while(s.size()&&s.back()=='0') s.pop_back();
	if(s.size()&&s.back()=='.') s.pop_back();
	if(s=="-0") s="+0";
	if(s=="+3.1415") s="+pi";
	if(s=="-3.1415") s="-pi";
	if(s=="+2.7182") s="+e";
	if(s=="-2.7182") s="-e";
	return s;
};
int main()
{
	double tl=0; int tc=0;
	while(1)
	{
		double x[5],y[5],f[5];
		int bad=0;
		char s[2][20];
		for(int j=0,k;j<5;++j)
		{
			if(scanf("%s %s",s[0],s[1])==EOF) {
				bad=1; break;
			}
			s[0][strlen(s[0])-1]=0;
			sscanf(s[0]+2,"%lf",x+j);
			for(k=0;s[1][k]!=')';++k) ;
			s[1][k]=0;sscanf(s[1],"%lf",y+j);
			sscanf(s[1]+k+2,"%lf",f+j);
		}
		if(bad) break;
		set<double> dx,dy;
		for(int j=0;j<5;++j) dx.insert(x[j]),dy.insert(y[j]);
		string ans; ans.resize(2000);
		auto work=[&](double*d,char s) {
			double md=0;
			stringstream ss;
			double p[5];
			memset(p,0,sizeof p);
			for(int j=0;j<5;++j)
			{
				double w=f[j];
				md=max(md,fabs(d[j]));
				for(int k=0;k<5;++k) if(j!=k)
					w/=d[j]-d[k];
				double q[5];
				memset(q,0,sizeof q);
				q[0]=w;
				for(int k=0;k<5;++k) if(j!=k)
					for(int s=4;s>=0;--s)
						q[s]=(s?q[s-1]:0)-q[s]*d[k];
				for(int k=0;k<5;++k) p[k]+=q[k];
			}
			for(int j=0;j<5;++j)
			{
				double prec=1.0/10000/pow(md,j);
				int u=0;
				while(prec<1) prec*=10,++u;
				string w=prt(p[j],u);
				if(w=="+0") continue;
				ss<<w;
				if(j) ss<<"*"<<s;
				if(j>=2) ss<<"^"<<j;
			}
			string o=ss.str();
			if(o.size()&&o[0]=='+') o.erase(o.begin());
			if(!o.size()) o="0";
			if(o.size()<ans.size()) ans=o;
		};
		if(dx.size()==5) work(x,'x');
		if(dy.size()==5) work(y,'y');
		tl+=ans.size(); ++tc;
		cout<<ans<<"\n";
	}
	cerr<<setprecision(4)<<fixed;
	cerr<<tl/tc<<"\n";
}
```

The output looks like:

```cpp
-265.3786-74.29574*x+344.81918*x^2+225.130398*x^3+36.610661*x^4
35.1581-3.27602*y+0.113946*y^2+0.412073*y^3-0.080117*y^4
-14.961
0.3769+0.50931*x-0.172598*x^2-0.0317501*x^3+0.0113617*x^4
-9.3762-1.54567*y+9.224426*y^2+5.413074*y^3+0.8106773*y^4
-3.7267-3.1155*x+0.011054*x^2-0.002775*x^3-0.0010706*x^4
1
4
31.8856+38.31442*x-0.94623*x^2-24.221891*x^3-8.086617*x^4
0.4856+0.08145*y+0.084768*y^2+0.0113*y^3+0.0001758*y^4
```

Comment: cool! You might be able to combine the constants in the final equation for better score?

Comment: How does it take input?

Comment: I think just feed the sample through stdin. @CommandMaster

Comment: Yeah I may try to improve on that later. It's a bit more difficult than it looks because of the problems with precision. @CommandMaster

Answer (score -1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 798 bytes, score: 3.323226 or 16.521740

There are two versions of the code. The less cheaty version will output an expression in form of `x * y * 0 + z`, while the more cheaty version will output an expression in form of `z`.

Obviously creating a "real" solution would bump the score down, but given that it's just a tiny gain and as far as I can tell it's a NP-complete problem, it's simply not worth doing it (some edge cases where you tell a 7-long number that's for instance `x+1`, then you lose a few points, but it's not significant this much).

```
cheaty/ Average length: 11618 / 3496: 3.323226
less cheaty/ Average length: 57760 / 3496: 16.521740
```

The code:

```c
float round(float x) {
    float v = (int)(x * 1000 + .5); 
    return (float)v / 1000; 
} 

char * find_constants(float f) {
	float x = round(f);
	static char buf[16];
	if(x == 3.142) return "pi";
	if(x == 2.718) return "e";
	sprintf(buf, "%.3g", f);
	return buf;
}

int main(void) {
	float x, y, z;
	long total_len = 0, amount = 0;
	while(scanf("%f %f %f", &x, &y, &z) == 3) {
		#ifdef LESS_CHEATY
			total_len += strlen(find_constants(x))+strlen(find_constants(y))+strlen(find_constants(z))+4;
			// printf("%s*%s*0+%s\n", find_constants(x), find_constants(y), find_constants(z));
		#else
			total_len += strlen(find_constants(z));
			// printf("%s\n", find_constants(z));
		#endif
		amount++;
	}
	printf("Average length: %d / %d: %f\n", total_len, amount, (float)total_len / (float)amount);
}
```

[Try me online!](https://tio.run/##jL1br3zbddz3rP4UDRkSSEu9Ne@XCHowAgN5yJvzEiSBwJA8MgGaMkhathXosyuzfjXm2n/ZDhCCOOfsuVf37l5rXsaoUVXjl5@/@@Uv//mfXz/99u9/8cf37//@P/3uVz/zf/@Xn7//n9f7/M8//sP7b94/@83v/vjzn/2X979@55TS@y/eX/3nf/3mot//@o//6fe/e/u1P/@H919xyfnlP71fr1/@@1/8/rzop9/87ld/@8u//90f/viL3/3xD/FnftKf@ZP4k@dvxEf4@V@//uRc98ff/PLNq//v//TT/5HH/3VGf/PT@QR/8zfv@pVb@fn9w3/6H3/zpz/8snzNvL5/@Wv97g//8ffn8//0s/NWf/n@0z/7qn/3p3/55g/FZecXf/36p9frXPX@D7/4ze9@9g9//5tf/fjx/vL9X//y/Y/nBb/9@9/93fuPf//HX/z2b3/769@dT53@8v2L/3A@@R/13@eC//zvf/PbX//sD7/8xe9@@tmf/tlPb/5//tyfn/f48/Mmf/6PP@c78O5/8q9@89Ovfv3T@3/9t//u3/3t//y//Nt/87/972fwT77f/y/@5v2HP/7@/NfP/ptb@F9@/vO/@B//5r/@f/7mH89v2l/rD/zVX73jlvzpn/3hX5//p7/4sz/8n7/TXflv/8x/N/Rf//uh88Z623/169/@4df/Pz9/vORffpL/0Sd43vt3v/rNT@c/fLP/4i/O4D@9/uS@9t/8w69//4u/@/X7/KW/@@O//5/ef/arMw//7FfnP37iTZ9PdJ/WX94J@/1Z/@oO@Yqfa0b88z9/0ldN652@@vnnp@TxlWp9fepXWvVMtjzz@9PWVxvrlb5aPhe2Pc6FJX/V0l@f/JXKPlN2nOvK@kqjvT7la6zzY/1qq51/tfPLM9q@@iznLVfK75pf9atUvdH58@Ndx3n33ea7fZV0Ltp641yaLl9cfj7nrPn8XOLn8tXKO3@dt/zk9rVHfp2loU/S@/eQXrU0WGt/Bs9YO9@jnm/zw3X7/DV98jme0fzlr7G5foz5aufv6e1y7udv6/vrA83z37XVt27G@RS5j/M96uBFeutR@KIt6z6n8/fXLnrf844M5Ph45493DZy7cX5o59a38wDqe652rknni@jPZT2ElPjQOekFa7c3d@S8/Lzt3HrhLvqmRQ/rPEz9wfMc2jr3PY2lO7L0J8@/@9DjzqP53dt7fJVSdN3UDW55@7qx9Rdrr3zb4r@YzvufL3jmSn7xB86bng90vlhmEqWmn8u5AXriZ8botpUZV8@p37Za3@3ct171vNs6P5zfVd2@Vvf5qZ5vOJljnZ/6ueRLd@fF3yq62/u9z9TpL00bPf9z0XiX8TU6D6mdW6M3mLoNu/FVSlmaX@XMc3093/TFk0n6iOd3XfeLx3dmb9KNX3P5oXvuZh5y1vQt50lpvumZarnoL0zN2Dn0rUda@s578STamaR6M1bQ6u3N3z6fbu6vvvW429i6Ypy/M8@6Kny86onDVFiakkWjMzM6z534rHMDsp58713rVy@f519Vs2zw9ft5Tz3fdT6XPsrQAz6/LlP3/7xg@ENpFvV0vpTvs@/dKucrscT5zDmfu1dieyhTX2qclVCSPtR5z755GOXMl3NZ3/P83bybH1DX2OaJFv2Zsy7PUP7aZzKcCX7@fOPW@wHq7u/dmR11sWXxRc5cGdV/5EwSfzQ2knPtOr/NQ1NU68iLSl@mn@98bs7in72xACrLq2qqnt8XT1/9mdU1dO4gd6V4l2DNl6pPemblR9/jfEWt7bMk2xk8r9T3166iXUPrRYty6cdyNhl9jXb@fWZZzcz/pM/PvD2L8atOPaO9F1vHmUFnU2pV9290bVxMjbP@z@ev7HPn4Z55ud959q/VqiZb1hZ3Psx5sPmshTK4ktHzZ/eZYPrAftBdT2CxoW@2@caGkAoLeXE6nB2P2atvNjRpq6bwWT6JRZb0Mc8mtPXPtPX1z5/ShpPZb3k4tWmWdd2tc5Tw@HJlI1/vfj7VOUDOtYMZrX2k6Z/nrebqbMLn1Xyic4PP4@xTP55HkbZeUM6/SmbD0Ifo/V49zwM/9/S8SD9nJsUZPftR8smkxaYHkPQZOzvDWLpBmjR9e3fO@vnMQvbtljuPeCYeRzpTUjOrjfOVVuXmTB0T63zUpf3bp9PWtnveo2uWazfQrT5Lq5/H0/VRy9nr9K@cuXAN9srFj2cX0drJmple@ZOlpNsVo2f5VOZc5i958Oxvm61IT/m@XAuH2fg9dCacbqRuyLmwbl10jnrmtz5W46xgF0oc/J@ix7x31QM@0@zDvjen7v55ut7n52QZtc58S5W1c4@IkfRjWvyY4g@fSa2Jdj530w6mW84mpTfTaaFt/Vw29LC4M2dO9umRsw95ala9xxnRicPx2hVw1OH5wIsaB7wPwMQU0LfcbIBj6ZjcZyJp4EyKybY1/PvEUcmu3RnxiaOpNf0W57lObou2fwUni/NhKwiqeiI@ks5daZ6STeuw6tXs6k1LTgdzfnNK9KbPoxledRc5WjpH6XnWZw1nblLWltd2vw/R078QzPUzW7JWx2b7q3p@U8cGXzc20c3zz5WIrUxmfkrs/Wc3fmmnYH4yu86314fRSvl40XGbtZvpsZxXahdpqZ/RrM1yLW3GPJmW2j5TY3LzM9@1sFumujVR@fv6tud56uukcTaMxhLRpqOpMLg6KZbRjpSZ4meynQDunEhnIThGWRwl2jX7mX1xAPjbKvZUkMu7VuaEAkFtcXolc7OVyU6YdYYuv7CeKXYigfOFvMWeSZmLZndeXKxgQXt1Zb/Xo87e/oaOmUS4nLN2vz0rUW99ew9VbKPw6sMJlDtrOemv6P4VR6ma7LrxWuOKCiL84rdVp/E5BRTMaY8ZRQcDkVhOJxRIeohz6EtOzfZzHJ9QXGuNReE44HNOFUXILPfFJqNAPNcTimy@yJx6hz66/6mhnNlPZlL8e/6paVWG54nvZOKeaJMmIuOfOs4JrTKx5PmnPt8NWM@M1k7jWcJTX0ObczqPXPeRcJ3ATjOTDUtxlEKwtwJ99rnE/ni@wTkHFQloxRQ9@cSSLd7ziZQHcXzRemfNLOa5DvbEfqA5wo89OxznvrKCytoEBeVdp1Yvj3MQ2JyT9@Q4Cmq95TW9ky7svp1nOS0di/M8@KrYloO694j4z0c9p0j10tZB1s68cuhY@P7p3Ew/AmcsY8XPbWs@rZNTda8nZuf0z0WTQXGU13IpfJLS2adybT8MVs7j7qOuOO7pmnv7uegsw8JESeX7lbrd3Ndd2CLOXGKQ6G45X2HsfJZIitZ8Bs9fbPyk1O/71QqbGrPhGVoObadX31RIpx1zkFCc992MaVfa79ivpi/TbqSxqjv3jHXCeMUqMaZTj28wziwt2glSZbY3ZaX6ObfmPYyfla56MbLd6zvM7pOM1@tvLDa9XidxhFfoWYTLx6QDbK0fgpBFHsZ5yNXcwBNrdp/bus269WeN8mR1J87mcraP83NhbmqSZ37WwtFTPmdA9QvqDWN0sPIKrW99vaR7OKqC0d6YJ5kppz1XYYm3w8q21ObmRO4697QMFe4pGqvERsMfIp/063y/7oT53C2@X9EeyRF1fj4fp5NtKVhMTIRKALq@r986X3Lj@sRJqD28KIbmFay5M9A9cP781oLewz9rZjqM2YuR82U6@agSOQ2cF2eyPPZDwq2pSFWohr57X08Ikdn5dWyUOJ79VYfOFx4H6SzTWEEsW2MnPHDY2MAl4hnXm3Akr2cnY9q/SEedhzbCpqwNdWbu/jpHSz5xvO6a4JXCUXLmxdpJj8BxvE6bXLXsy3rwG716ncR/eS7kyk47SiW7ZX@cg3txVt1cXlyeHycO6UTxncdN8p1I2bb3gX0238kfVzqsJaswJLFCU1dkWH2KVW2reyquF8iTG0duLEb9qTN3z6leq041LXhF0@dOnQOieUXpUSahQF3BDaF61dtlMprEps5HWKTf2SCKchtv/Mkzp@vJZpbQeQefYz17rTYjsCQNfjaaeQJkyLB5KqVWg7jaJYVOnA3kvc9H1rzXRpgIGzJ51GReC1C6L6nO75qCageapNWarcylnoTLbO2rXWHmcHSbia8J4TXXugINb8tN22Vaz8lV@HogVsQUmjdnv9HLC5mrHpJDkByRthNAZmTv3uT1TfMqL6IfH1RVe0VOkSlr@ilJGlpRTD5m5AljlzBHvlqtXhDaL3zI@xbybYneKkcU2VX2PkHmJlxCUXVrztyKMYzlNT0Lv@ZvMrkLt6BM4tfiI1lPphsK4voCmqEwyEulskGdrY@JppA9K2QRXDoIXHUr99uXnH@eZPY7gSm@JSd11FIcDgP5hz5lARbTGuZf3MRdi/9ei3@R9i2gyrMhVAKlrjtcBLp0EBu@bReOsRxdNgNc5zMXb8UGYs/3q548wxl8FSTgFcJ8VPjhZW5Mrgt4SwQIitsyaUYkOGddKEZTGigoRoNLcA5rh4UlhGeOc8MJjLYyZUWj5y/P8@X9hwCTi0LOLoAyEITpZ6Obp7n2isTuPCnS0FIVd2jZgPKeA04PKS3H8Cli15O1CffS5@DvM4OHkNShA0nILe@ZtXGu86G5agurYFvLWamB1kpmwyb8VvCsQS0dA5cplR@GBbcwD/SwTzZ5Lx5GvYmNzlal0UZeoPMkE@drn9c@pbwox@am03T5mWxvtUmxHrepOpU0REDIawwKdEDzcoHEnK/xZicW1AZk4gRdG6vhEr6/jiufIO2szc8AovM5ZLw1O4bXgxBq5btB7NyF@nXHRec1yi2ngvvBpQrcwelWJzZZoLOcd3oAST/400@iUN2CE3U753CGt5xdLf0hYT9n7VTdm/Pfyp38NTS7PyerOJ9MYEQCZNY8zmBPnAwC4FjzICM8WiNz5w8M9rFEbK0Nf2qoOoDXNqboSMEMkGBmQ9FidXibOrPGAPf0Ej6TWhurMJePd16v8EX4oIy/6oaxpVA4@RrvPc7RUJ6YV6ne@chlaQmD0mnv2eevn3i0UR/pfmlS9qdIfxpe697JhF0p610Gb86rd9FyKs4YlpKVc/Bqh298xa0ctirsUS5CaHbinL4JTR0HqaTByVf0YZSjEYo6Uqz8ycpDUYLtSw2KzWFgTXtAJfU7h8ImGdKT0SHFZjIKq0H7pU44AYL5hDiFmEF5sZ6MJtLHuJvQ5naOk7MSLoarmLQJdWsOjBWMVtCNPM8ezd8sTZN0a7Wd124edDVmUoQrbuFPmhBJQUbdgNKRU2Si@JMexzPNzR9/v4vjamZxAdFt2fWj7LNKu3OOtZEJR7VuTqzV9QNRulJbQU7aKIj2@nbYJVS46ye2eUMwitI2uKpwKj7HmeDnsu19b8RSKW/hV@zs2mIjFRzgDmduKpwS6JgCw9ah0PVLJSiZWTQzeJ7mydTvG@jrSJoxJCNEWYpI@HVqWvaF336@M@fmq0v3lNeDLz01LcXKlk6goYyitBNVGRwCZnfRQ@dMPytnN20HebD4tw6/LVSKSdHYWD2Dz3prQh9d7TEGIPiwKo/YxlrLRXNisFKrIDQ5C7sy5m@gFFHJOS9tgWQ1vbLFK1tugMzzLcB665FxU7RVTX9p8i2yj91crBvEVZq8SizPqzoFmBOTAJk40AETAKLZ4OYa0v4vJMP1xw2QcdJcA8OtUkkEC6vaeTQDBFUqyKSgl4lslRLydXe/MSvnQPFB32IsUfeklLDuZfnCTftepf2P4K3EQOb@KPvRTQCZcsgcm0MhMlXalZxerXeO0sm5E5OChlIu7UGNtdFPRta7diKFI5HzKXWZrX@RV85stK@xjCdViElW4GKrgniSm3Pb6lh6QdS7fHOagZXWFGbuM/F5GNtbub@xHqerYaTV5LwNSFV/3Ocna41yz1AVU4d6B8leJLa1T4NoBIbE6llwvgLwSrh/0qqznzGptwu2582UEzmfbLENaYOZZ87Fsh1UUuozWA1QFkWn31dmDgQthv3DlZOaiRL@O5YMegtHq@/RnDFqLjt6OlvJHSyuFCbOvDtIMCAksN@hRDH03K1/8dLd9WjZQnkUc3ceWNXPyo050Kd/XV0uKSqGaUBHGT@vseP66Zz5zPNxvje7e68c2yIDnFAV5LY40FbeozutzICkTJnP@R55uL4NyNUaMfKtnot7oEdi9Ds7cNfprqD1nAA8iwYYRhVG5Ueg8918xrDSp0kQCkwyT3gUHXVpVhfetkuGywH5oLo4CJLyU5V1HWvMJ@7LbxMQPsxiBbiVisv5ZGUrwdf0HD7EBGWRf/BUF7lF1@7QqqqF1fkW@c@ALdDPFFlKNDkDXJqkHMC/tEhT46AgalYA6A@vEEV/j@3G1VJnkUp3BTS2KO81kwhygEm@RPsEa5GTMOgpZDqCC86YIgrOemPK3bueEjhi3TYuBPupenLb2R3VONJKindxzGl30oamrZ1jgwrmiBpYys6hjPSNOFAEDrosQFq/BbNFIBR4oPZSF2Iym4/Ch5YoArksvfUjSDWouioW5P6V7Z/bFQM36BsaSKC1uikKYwlT9XiNliajOKlrIzbBZAol1L5EJGgOg7LXz1NDiexVYM/ZZtu4QKUmojAZxSDEJSNq1XUoE2De8kdJAE8eRzKuZbwABTZ3M5shMGJRERIOaC4nGChdeIATNm@@76Jg3fftHVWbpnSLw2Q6utKMGoUIKt1Kn87uqboIBylnkCDnM7QouxoGH2fH8JAKDq7Ynq3IQ4YrXcfyyJlfXZNUtUmPaEq4LkulqBM2andTLCsGQwwR1ngjVQh4r1MI0UjzniGKrdUVHY8ZTiokm/FXDTqT793P9vFlCUTt@XCFjKmvHz5vMxjU1vPN@1ZoPfTECUJHLGgt780uMgsQjM6a7Tdxfij042S6RPZrkkF6QSWlBRw8laKA9g/nwqZDkAQq0lrEW6x2gQrnnyr@Gzdc0/G9hgRSRGUpm4IjZJMjeTlnVbXkbfgwuRCiHbtE2UyxVSa2KvdWaZZk11oby7fx4g6QoYSxksdCQWuupRDeCULvMDGKM2EhN4TH1XV69lRiLG3EHCJmBkE46@c@8giHT62mQeUbhJ6RbO4A66dRBU6abFRpuqimZVRckDgPQ/Usr6zzxQwEQTYQSGdKR3YVLosSo1Ba86Kefy6H61qPgob1S53GmqmbmdpYkMqKPvFkVnJpp9w9GOZME2Wrvx4CQXENYJsrlKYJOpRm/QAzJBo/MebYdsBQwCJdM8rQkpa3yJKDckMemINo0ybPHgx/dOPVcdvgiwjLb@Zj6XjaTt415ab2N2Vp2lIVup3V3sAXicaddJA/K4sYHBCDSaFDNq5MLHatb@DjBmik7OM85zf/dQGcTLzEf2v7JLhXPY3/5sNtExALIMFur4BJDN/4LDbifDJncJnK3j/3CspWN3lt5wH4EolMVQ1VWzvJcfLvNswa5Z5eEEYNdI/PzdQWZgxauzmUEr00p0lWOzYXF2JXMndvAPouSw@rNoIHbaoUWwhSu2qhhCjcqOoYdSzwLsGTRiaUTC0gKYfG5ewxcz9cwgpYNLU9V2a8jvVpngrZQ9XOtm9FFVi8aEAcAwKZk4psRWDOLAlPtuIjcT4NV/KXkwkveX2Z4bCXYVPNJmGNmnPwppQUbsXTvNRA74QPM5xzeZknso8djJrYbMpXC9jThDjqkH07ZwYeXXqjDeKZiJOEsa/9QLtaW3r8LBQid7EgTzAId8awX9URpVmtVRlowrn7ndcMgxCKC7JJDy5ji0znEfNfAxNmKFGDJ7yMkQIYVVkgfpUTqsR2CUeWA5UaZdWGtoL4QaULTqQS0nZDs3MfBEcJZyPW5DMB9nahdc3bKrsvSczs21VzbXoEF@fUOZFOLtqTMkWCbBLiNMPMMeVZAKPqoHCkEOTNc6pqI6tmhPIRgUDZ4atpo5oz0PE0z3Q0CQgw4MRnhZMJ5SUTGHUhiKZBcwO0As5Ng5vF5qxZyAClQZMjske0zRFWDf8sFNSI3M53hIedyTwVlTAdVeJp7KZD@BbHDoGUMAMdA0SLohd4Ni2dG@QNnGiLPCVl9p7tcnauxIJDZ@T2OaXkxUPamqid5hgw81E3rd8hQgI41HXGUCVjOe8XxO5EbA5rTGkpEYtqgEMTrREvqsqSud3VkzOXHZgCOBGMZyC1HHWYbARCNHcjIZ/hbYWIGwC8NxDq6o1Mx9jQflciWOxUPUTZyzCetQmJJAIYtC9swNfdOn5fwfOpbGLaRVqPmwFi4unSlgmlbxAgJ1YuuQdYo8naG7fKLxuvqKpqLjUTmDh2OimNDseklQXC0Dkqz03YZ4FUiJRJc2uJwZq0SiuYOYfO@U4LZiK1EXasE0@ftDFK9s27ETNs@@b7dcOceEJkKJvZMJH2SaXQFW6QRyjkFqCLaoRDnEAniNrspzB23XbzUEQBWBw@mqsD/FjJySSLqUgNCtD9R0lrLq40E4UpqVyaoK9brRGQ1d5OvM2P3qYh5ohWdw8eImyE7l9aUqD7YwpiJjFwYdKwtm7JCjL/9CZbwXGSlzOkLzPI2VKTqUxU95i221V4rZ/PvCSKCv0oB/8jCnMKWWuwb5oOJO2sc97t4MP2UIoX69nJMgxnPRMdO6rBzq1Kp78JrOrzSU80dL6FXmrmlbarsYFPDFkrYDtPR4mBn3MxrtEMYg8oK4Xq5IJbTUbeHTiqgLhUelP9i7Aeugrlh211BFAaRQeteapIxA0juBEie/NO9Rm8Ios9@jMWJPkEfPgMFheUTbh9RoNGelY/jwdcw3X3y2E5dwEuOqkF1aGIdpTcBdqfuHEFyBXCHxR45@oUSEVvzutEtqpOEiUYvBv/YlwoR6NMpj9cmvM8Y9xU/L8vTXFiCH8/E3bPE7j1V8gW9F01HYuOcIAop8mrlmfQ2Z1DuDtm4JXS3x2q3F@f7d@XQVJpZNrFMFklCbNWZUi284ryVWRWCvBIqE0lmNzOUforEmIBxCB@KZOcZFPNt1b5mE4Nkqn3CUbpyZaSdTtmZ7rqXk4Oq9ALHAVuTdH8P3dDyHCFJEfEcd72RBHd57thek1C84oQU6goZl7RydbeAD/6MTu2VnnHrKRGxXf74ghkohBy4smRfJh69WhbOOHkpDJo2I76cReDxNTPfjOnTCZt3QOwN0n7gD1pGrC2XKhVJTvT3P4Z4pHuEj/nS1NcJX4uvV72A8vRoiTgcjbjQvYp4K7q00JqqKgiEuSeZGaNy/IV5Fr/NLjlwrBICgQfin8rcWzWqZuBCAMpG0zhl1lZYsXouK4RdBN0fZgMqRvb9cUNqs5mJ3Ml0rV9EsZsmhcIqTKZ4IGZ0DDMEyEKNRmj@z0yUZ@jcoDx/Qqu3vnXe55b/6pBkRH5TNT97LVpXHHC3T/JCVITsw/O0pjUMrPzyEQZORAQExSzp4QmTaK0OaLAnJlw2q0GYZ1fMCCjoihpwMM6gyZSMe3LCg9MsavoSpJTeJi/mexnOxeQoKaLb8vmzE7XUbfdyqLUd5rfOlW21QWN5ynYzJS9mUqQawBCLSj6NEInPhucX9QrYxmsnOZIe2km7j98gbMyc2Vz9803Y6@QavPW0G@nUkhT1fTplHVsYSXaCD0/KF3wBRr7Nrxoa@@yM5XCz4IFIMTmtzPA4ZOZ3zYma6YAA8pgbrG4jdXckrcfYH21Zy/LLQh@2g2Hw75K9qTz0ACN2dHT0B7pGglRi2gZHVavBYo8pHSjO@ZsmCLBzk6dUVH6NkMpk1R2F2wURRPbQuqo3VUrvT0ZOZmLdysrJxTy1AuqfajeNbR926fhyU8intdLfISYJ19nPJphsKo47O78rQma5ZMnw6TX3n5WyK6Whpj6lEfU/EJmxGPSc0@E99q@TFOt5u4g73n57ICyGy8nsiKLMOy3CGRD1ZNWqIiqf64uvyxoDOnLlQgqaSFepOBanZ0PqEeIwc7kOWtG6bIyYRUIBFUa0Q4p5@JJ9mSYxnvyggDbSn6S1QrXQiB6peC0ipNmjSkj9FkKqsoqyypfaxscxhP5dg1BBH/bjGIFe@eOEyIrwjE14Fw5wCo4g9YyLWSTHJz7@LJQz8uxdj0BIAQrdcp7oLZwIdrUbSohyiL4RCaSSlB1Dj0tHApvbH9ak2clUHjQ9N@kIOc5jxNkpqVTZxpCUoKrK08aobXcmL5nrx9z6USGcVatVVMgPwWJF4fgXllngv8wnE0GoMb4L4eBd6VF/B6Oo7OQsXwPK2mA8Le2CT7byE9FpCqMcSAJNNclEfhrr1LGMq0Iqshxjcfor2q3qpkAqKIEPTPOI7GKqN7fa5SzFwo1cY1gQmL9et9IJHR2COUjIm@Rpp8TxpIQGKcKWEBKTWCTlJqKjLU7lu9mdgzzF11@itKqqECUp7KpQSLZuPwUOLCSPHNTCwrGRHmqUWShKLKvwtc0LtGXX6HPC7aM7tDMD3M1P2oJiAmkaMaz4Mhpe1O5JAS/GogXUgLQbOAPVj@C5Gq34ZgMVWWwKVaf9mfqaL8iyUSXbK69jt4lXPxlUDBx5C/U1uki9grnutSXBDOWt@o2WiLaLEW4@knFDuvtXQbhKu@qDInjkWrtgBzRAIxb23G2tqmwIImlVV3vMFellRjKvBl0sxhRHI2qZ90rRECwpsvvEgCF5YAgzAFfz@zP17xPbBFhOU7hEotgR7pFupPIg7Prb3oIurVKxKkmdVB5ZBt68MWnF@gPzGJt8SZlwNPgz4sFDZXFfNYN/D/g6X381zm92nunWV/3isKuxtBDgha6yzWZ01fIgge0vUNlLf0ObILawWSDl2necxC5hBk2a@UJFGD5idYV4IsXv7Dy0NPuYcGmY8pvQnGM6eGsR1p5x3T2JzBtDwl9tqIJyMGEleGJj2CIp4LAkQzoXR01@yRXqc1MayPKKvNVmA1MjOwfBd74NNHZ6upwtfgxe6BZepQQZTCiw1xX8Ai7SULUDU1x66YIZbME2XH0EnKXUtYTeaNEAxdOMGKgEdZ5cZRkdXU3vZUbWcl2GH@hU0PFOg3mZc5PE4udhg6XHE2PaOxvHyvLPkIjM9mInvQEVRf6GWwPw@BmOZulQUJgtJkdl2odfB7na0boxWe5rN4GQqcCWh4PRaKBV2WHPwsHBNFzP6tSqmdzQMSivYNDFXCdSgs1FYE7pYsJZoYAyualvxoChrAZyMpKxRgwzmkmFtf1GpQ1M59ElElgxMUfRYFNh19S2HUkuOTuD2TaemKmKTcA8sUUta7UInDA0pdxUC@M0A5qRZNzx88iEThwrUCBxUCVVi9X@LysptW2/LICMgEZvkII5k/5ELEzMaOmdQeZbLqJng0bSul@E/m7QL136P74W1TkqkPyndvLBUPd@GWVNmhURkcG96szhJ6NrarB8eDtHH8DuRr/ay7K8TdaJDjdlU/Xn9G1apPgu1jRUw2D9VaubD00zyBT62WJk14lBtK4agvU@MWWKcs02ud8aJxquxI4WA/RzhZeuz@O8wLHhlxncsV6zCE4mvMIeuw2PirqgSUyH54j3wSlqAuXTphxegC0MDKgLFbn1HA22qtRfEsEyBSz4/jpoom2/nQhM4O05PQ1si9x@lApWLjFNupcyzTQFJH@CB7uDBHJjtJZ6P2HA3Yx98vZlHxHl4Nrwcsea0iwk8M9Dzm3jaoCQ9lRcLIa@V6lqDFENd2qpgZKAHGKcpgRlLyrUUqXtpcFMWzWmN/MgOXgOA6EKNvUvxweIt00vzacLbnaow2vCLYaztqZs0DQinZYHBQgzk3rBDjeLZD26gTrQjfNow/uncG97mC8r2/CVguddHuqt37uN/Iyy/4jGplP90psgHgSnxDWjN9enAbxuPyX@YTQq9vlDg3X86tSJQUtyqlz9a3G82KLLtlMojaPskgmkC0@Aty8wFCG7JkROiXkgHmahjGMqKmYRVmsjHGBfeXjGW5P4PqCZA0L4wGCYLxEpb9Bb0oEV4k4rkXlZvgzw2j8ysb9QOYHNyd1e9MkB4AKWBRJ2v0ALwpZKnioBg9Lyee9KlnAr8LaM/bAG8Kb72CG44Ikbl5WspmeG@FIsSgqiK3z5bJbZTtxvM@nMeZSkJm7qqEPA6vGpOcyrBVhN3JJAAaqCCKZYypb@zUCXYyaiKS83htOVI/@1I5C@A3tZiG1t0dgsh5wXo5oDJ5LMvi1XKmDwjMjQDMVqbM7ENgpc9UmY8ohRVMzF17W0vLQRvya6kfrM2R6zXWNHIUHyzPWoiSQQpVheqtXjxnbyWmM7YHsFgObv3FSV7PmNVZfrpTzUih2hfNr2MNgaUWcbRKEtQQLVxTjFSUITj4BelMUt1dQ4z@2ZwIW6ny4cT@IQv7ksNBZlku1JVyGzIyMBeljAd6eI6B8AVyqfvBhFF3EppchWcl56KtfGxLr9ipHc@/UroPQKO7K@dR9WqVv7oQwh3rJO6lbM8g/M6RqC5xckyvLWKcP1ww9vD81phzonXx1kAuTLRaH6SAAWBlo3oxpRla6dS59mFnZQYtLtMVC5wkh@JJHGyjNWCJHvlwct1eO3rHaYUrUBC0dIclt3SpjBZhfS9vWM4urtQI6yE3PDr@qc@7Pa@CTqDgIyMsJqxZ9QMNPmh46OeplWiTApztm1SHUtn0HK3lUpmR1r8sAWSDY/Q6Sf8WRc6KXfSICw5nLRlxaDXe4ULV11vAMJhdTDM3@cGkG8hb0@ePbol9LxFW5WqabvjwlpWX4YQzKgmIZD3FqmfCU71j@StfQ674w@yRprDi4Ac21A6U@o13rm4@NHEb4ZinJSf65QPshV@bXOqfCdopoI/kJboOK1ZY0HGEJAgXb79naUCMVBPlyc9BmrKDAHDFooCL17qkE43HrMN4S5n5EtLW8w5CCgvaogQlQ1RcZ0UjEcC1tWkzY4D2ZpP3K16HKkQtIsE21bsZmyB6872Wrs4CFQJxb3GIJWsUReKXQwVzPJZ72dnyn8nZWcM5ugJcBgbXOYYcsNq9p9vVa6yJW9kZLrkAkE6UKwH66VYlGDNwhDVaO6Qozv1muYTDc@0@1N4Qz7QbfZiEHyJ2p2ahO@XTdeOEUl4qc3SYj@oFsZrvXFU6pESwlCnb@WFY7s/O7sslNgOlOJGoS1Q5doYNYgjw8l1Cyn03gfDuyZyp7pApTWQ0gjrdPycA@LkN9rNUSGCnRDeIRsV0yuZmmy/ki/FYB4llJolRbwSDk7nOieiUkJoiYDEVGNHpXqhrSt6gqFAHNicRm2@JBa6meM152TcYyiCkIQST0ckWyWPq5r@hdECV1hRWmXLplk3RCwINlCQ3Q1pKLOf07oad@@9xFq3IiN7xHl4GRGRQQayT7M1ZQPLJatxwE90YBarsToX/TrGfRnburq5qpEH17VA2yUN5lxt8KDkeWHkVjDS18c4SWYmhbfyosy0PBxk54SJrFhvWHnDsncy@EW92ZGr44mYyZkBhbihXyLEJ@ULgGRaKYkpwdgwnu/YE@reu6gFQOJ1KjiVBm7uGACNWM5kxXmsNfMEyndM98327BisoS1/rAK8zZVbNYKpvGvC2rUmrmte2/AILHzmPSqhB04GN7CMnBxNpd@1n0dziqWcUhyQrWAeuBGQlVit27UiS84RYCu9IxGmB@7sHN7bhPichkRTa1r9ztsWdjAeVJSiNSxHUI3aBzRzh4DR8Mg6dig7kI1OVWiFQZBy/TlTKfBrKEwTIj5mTbHrWlWbuOlhbPu/BH9HgmPQJYmxLo@DBLKkEwtsBONKJewG2to7QWNI8vmwyMZUemHdC73XzCcq24RDVf1iZAPjx7HuJzAkxbGCABKyksIFD/ook7h3s10WPiBSas5zN3SqazgVHhP6sy/O5LCh8PE7KhDRtEyoKAl6MG3UjTdoIqctM8BXTQm7QDUOzVy4cCZUPKONDqa4xySeVifjaz5vnhyhWM5fBDqJwKZl8DlngF5pMshRy3zWIrEhdaHbnq9kSYZbZ2uB/1sPNQycqMosVfKsDzm31i2pFngeftFvTWQtTDVif5OdGpSEsgsBVHC2rAOSZ1zrYJgz4bPFBjrAnnwhhrUDk7ea2GrL@8skkMGh1ZMx1c1EIuV8PYw2I1J4vmFo9r06moCEUKJfnqnI1D0@cokYZlwGjQX3bDCjWk0YwKeqD7hE6gw6wY9geqZw@bTl7sxhEaiWYEQ9i74sNdTTOUoCI5EymQbZ2t72rUjp8VrTpLU0GpI3tDuSKoe3nzSNCiRI7m9zPodNInZq9GYRO5@jm0kLpIQJLC6q66dN3sOoKSAAdYI4fZQuiJoQYpSsil7Alqhnzut3h@4tiBS5HDqGrOxJa71Nae2J90QZtB2Sds/XKuVWx7RQnwPK9k041q4CjDa2yjK4JOVtKO9r6GDNjfhcttWZY2LZiB1dBcdapccYgxpNnDftn4CyRO@Om1h1o8fDhx0ezof6tjmnIvSl9GncG179BGxgz3n6ECfFpgWgtPQ0sbWmntpfOynrId2c4DG/joaQqTXQtT60gLhVDgVoWLQbMN6zQzRZt/tSa3IEKSFsIOKckiovzGfStYBcrZazF6vcyj08/5uivNEm4TlrVI9RHlGhaISi6vSx2plIWBdd8hcLLhSBguQXrvbPy3fBC6j/P1NXFRKM7Y2FQsMQbTiUCulfYy6E2UgTusBucYhi0vHN2W7F5wnQoHBZESCrbjj/vI@grHNqK7yUg1OIBtqlYQLyw7km1MhOEGd8lk78IOevEdJR533E3ZNoaDbRUFm@fi4C80w8w/vEeHL6Ldv9yUJOV5DZArlWWoc5tNGRq0JdCjz0CWEbo40N@GxJF/WUxLNDTeLhhMI1iiwGTwq@1HnIejI4NZCnegNVjQpEeerSRWPrnNQJxzXGpnthmnVKz9dQu0aOYRY1KBwOqM6TikkEKkZSaYbpOYxA7XfAxaVeTIpl3d8a2JmuW07L/rBe8yyIOodmdu7b7HNg9L@dPgvMV5ynPfh6wNGjquwyy82nFPDMZ1iAa7jEvYMYzd4AW6sUAreG5dJ01t02aGZj8dwBpL@uvVvBa82HKkEx0gk@00s7MIjXIC7pOOhG5Y@g3pkshb3KMTKs@wZXA9Dc42NVrzDe2PVYFXbcLVnQzYFSaDEmnvEG7mcvFE7TFE/Sv8OTP0XMR60pkM6dqfrQ0jhzCSsTQpnYMrOQQXoHdySElPSgBtqqbEEEBJuN22Z7BeK2EV5mIw9O32VYkxXGVBHMjaVnX96Z1De28inw2d0UQNi11t5TFcqzP/DE8LMvjsfHqY4@yMacIHMbh1CxD2VwKbX/YMwADFKn1yasrj3iC9tpmVJhcTPedhfN0sb4oiC5dyYjj9NZsyxYJUzN6T88nH/LXbwhCjUKms900x7MhIMl6dAVcl4Lbv4bmRmm@Dygrgt/kI1E1tI/tpoSnewLJwGMjTc3MCMgx0tB71seXdq9kKlbzDBygBX5xGCPjLuL5OkUoUG8tBCWzXSnajZsqhdMNDrZkYAw/RbyVy6pTGOLAYHeo624YOaSsk7PuAw6ZIAQ5F1zvk1oVldTnPhWpjQQ71clwXZtu5jGssrWeKIi51NO6GHpXZIWaq9ibVPDiZ18siGcJaTEqufZp1zlSvfRZoB2z5@kkEL8RSGOdM1SbQ1VxxJZvXFRrIxR4TCSy3htIy43WokQg3zfJKF/CdWEFYtBBD4bNl3UoJsy4DLBTdwsS1X7uEHIaEeI5KvOhnF40STGpH3cdmUdzroZXwRvuWx5vwBLll9Ct6bohByTm1lH0KktqIWlia90lklNUX216w23mpfEXxXOV1EylcffMHJizc5sAtMkHFheXboBl@MXaS0/saLBV8484O6FHjYKFhyyN7NAMsVNtv5RM1V6cPKxklxxZipjvcoRMuwtFzqBZzR@wNMQCxBsThV0wjWgbIk/m@rRNkR687IoFCqLjkWKeHuEIn3oyvzK80L1Jbv8yRKxa39BSmFabqRFnbHiXoRm/ktF1sLKZutw4xxhiyhEG8l9ef7ZwKitwVnBNWWCH@lHPMuGiMQ4xmaziIcNYv7RY0z2IEmt4Q@uTFp7s9s7VrhP5YNwuL4@p@Hy0KbxMmmfQ5sWyIRxqsp/CRcma8BL@Isv5OIfnogttcMHDFICx/TPew76cDWlvjhKNDh2olV7Ie9dCHjgFBXvuI9ykq9Ci9CMe8xS7HzSeJeLVoK0Es7WkyYEiZUEK51WUxlNK2yxwOVHB4mYGeg9@YNYnvuvZuSYX0fYMFo0IAJQ7UkCphQhe83plBCsAJR8yDahMdm7ZANVhDx5E@s0nVCYZDFtip4yRKiIitWtiSTPNimPQlZaj/uPFZVcC6qZna1A@SQAxcE3lA5yQf5l1tjMcMyi1AeKRZ7glBvtBjm0tfvtdyKOo48YDFWyFHHSmKOwsuWEYaP7MrUkZbd40hqyFyVO/jdbQkonZwX7fsjJBaufq@an7GdjUrLJrH7QL0sWi6kdBi1nuj3QT31/hOumVl172NLRNLYw9h0lNx2q2BHhCyqc4rFHq86PJ0wl@b6kcQDdKl5XLu@bysNyX0UWsHmNnAIDSyoquGUzwl5YoUX@FQldjSQ9xHlTTCL587HJSjBokSIMtF6lqd8RpJyMu0GUvsE16KlSTNJR4V5geqd0h0mJTqgEfvcZ7HQPXtcnRpbFEJrdB5JBEA2HdXcIiTRzQ3yze6sVSGS2Yt6kJ0qXnVGz2m7HY1dndz9eakTfsrQiTbeygQz83S2wKXOpiKeTtOynTKwidtSnGZFgZoBOM62jpO1JqeaUVlrpzkXBG4p0R5tCJq@9KsoQ@/FAzn8kl0CIOytVqm2G7hLsEKtounKiAZqUOGFy/LBCF93jlS4GlxAK28nkYhZwtwStHvKaK5Vl@XHiqeUjfDKQoO2RbfXTE9vMT5gN5F4Vq/pzSVO0tKNupMnPPtLa7dJUoBpAGpu7GK4S4HzNNeMg5sEQ8vmBvONjlYVQ1qUFSb98vlapMhKOPF4ZTkA4nahw76jV@lz1vz5SaOEewKfbm@jZ1/p@gQZc48aBqg1gTUUgxF6LVd1AJqbbZ8VRkfa9Fl7oJVc6aXQZJjgUV3KkjcjafEFuTDlhZOxGD6tPBMqcoqlFr0lKo4dhWSOLmqYtMDf@AMLEw7PvYWFYAsb@taQk9sF8/HQwnnYHEwrgNR9cSR1vEZqeRpUiJeT6Lk/ALvjsfzyP1YUDxbpX9J1yDDZjyPqEpzfxLm0SaikHjBq4zOGhYuV5frrG2YTxnVJig0CUnXeARD@EoV3nzslG@E/4kco4LZd4v76CRl/x/vdxhDhJvgCEl8mPEX0yF1/A9adrDxoEqzhtoAqzPfBUCm6JZyM4nwwLX/E52H7HaF0w8pY/VL61fw4BQSJBUrHO@4F4i8vJJsUynCYwCqbZsxP91kPqnigaRs1fCMq2hKf0UsiQYtie40FbXaMryZQ/NuSxuXdJhl8Be2Cgs@QxoZZHjBOEc00iWuRPGnCfa69fDpBmnZACqup4Xd308QIqyizTD5w@5sBOhjfJ3BbeL5icDDw7GQPNSHHdVgPqI3cEYqi1X7AHfHAKEamk45i3@drFvz8V/NrC7hyHQmfbmqP77JeHdz10mS8f5hKQUv2GI9bGqcWmUEqMOq3OwnXIk0c7ENHVpjNKnbDNC8bPjkzk/VWjf3P1E2viTufkW7D7cXVB6VDXpCH3fHCMdzeir4v7kYO8NIHNeU4kurbUGmXaGHnY4W9Z6XO2AUgD9sYJsjWAf7NVSGrJCrAb0nllx@4d2T@0CyLayMV1gTVPMwSqP/Aafr2/a/wJRIzIKMPWH9Kzh5ha8Gh6U1ANU6FrilJhl82qDGEQHHx7VefaJJpSoSEOh6WdwWd82hIQcP9UQF2cL25u4YwgSk@@ZcninM09Yde0xZ1jNUvjwJhazHEEemhaOq4T2DO5qLaCFJO88Za7R6yD0VQDGFa42biYhW1SwZf9vCOXNsvexekamj9gGSb5VpDqphii4SOPHYtih5d5rQH5tZrdkJU@SZMWKTLVd8npc55q6wfzJMUWBsdjlRfO1YNd4mfg9VHl5RbqcMsi8UK3sxl7Wb1axRDW4QpCApj3FhchLTZTeZHOs46FqDLlyZjBeKQeZH1Zc/9jlok3ptxawLB1W5k9KYzyLCqC0WSkcvw1i2jJOd8cDufwZ3tKDsaK6juMyuMh6aQyaF7CAd5HHP23AvQvc4cBnnFdlOCbNysCVXQgyZNWOfIxqSWBhdUw9dSwqzFwiPJi9UABss9a0pqnxNxXAkfKuHJSx2FDKuaRFY8E8PIWnB/aauZ6yShRqnjzHTAxsUo@/LRnXHD9GVPlHutwqQXhZhA5P3VRGAEqnSt07CEZE6Wi5NzLSiFGQXU7klT/Aj90Ao0WTBmq0wfGr@ytqey3hFXanhU3xle4Zp4Ym4BWoxGTd8WhqUcz8QjDZpKgFlwJrvRqF0mCpHy0grp4fRvB4/R7sVnDCgQJmOv@ICU8I@Nvgwugy4P8OKURsMk6dTNMtwFJI9TivocVvTvHFnmBTEMzr2iqUQq8B@l/L55VYLB532NIvdx6qNGHzcABTexli@3C7F3vfFRqdMZP8e21hDKXLJc6mG9grWZAASZQ0tuZeP@wj3p6SdDpWIRFVvOgtyfZlR3i3fdJsTLVXWtePpIif1HGB5F8xFx4ugihSzxpFrcdKgECU7kchjPKxeEM@CoteZJeUZd2bc2BpgdPrl8KkYpHOjAToq5@utSySVDCuBr29HFSClsApMRqUGbK6pEQUQ0yuKKD6wA7rC2/96/jcSFEvXmgcKnq8RWn7cfNVaYRThgqZasnbJjLxZrUEMjiS4S7PAol5OhkecsZzb0p5L5M5SgxYTdh2FKG9GgAi7yhg5uMMcFMKqS4IF15gc8KdiVmYgQt@pmM1KH7q@CMlwsvMxSeYTxDT5ZWx3KaTmJG@CIQsHzn7tHjLV8Iit21C51DuGZdLbCfjzQj4suvYYClaxyZY5jS9a6k4owJNWr/qkdnW1Hh8r@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@WOtacTVX5LTVM1WHAJ50HTQx8etKEySItaDm0RGquvR8DtsCaGWg3k1XhE4VmJ3mv6l0Pmi4bP8N2JpyFF4dFCIFQkvcxZm1I8M9Se9yX4UQjkpSsU3wJ4lBD0zHQ@eAMmogf4vKRZx3mY6DVjobWW10E1JbaN0XwK9Z7FzLc0/2JvXF29EUGwuu3YnbGK0fh@4TfQN4Y@9JyqXU7i7@qD2Dzs61LKYsOJkEK3wkNAofC/MqIMZaooa9AjNqQET7qoCNfAVNZNnPZWNfas9WiEPJfZiymyKd74rBC41zFkIgjMa6W3vxaZQQLxg0lSMPy1kVFuKrucyOF@KGFGmer7MV@t4RJRtZgNIrrG2rmWp08kUy0K5JEBNBm7P7K7kRB0bLWEjhgbhCaeyET98Iho2LgALZEAukp19Hsn8gqlxUyq5VcTbauDS72ELrx5f/vlKTsFzO0UodgyvbhCQbPLPdDjfYuV3wWpB/Bo0eolvTLbE18yrttTXr7QkWOxOFoIyqEdPRayUdTVqHdTqTSiNaMCfvobBWXG5bREtBaMTkTm/JLWba250SJoxgUZJaD22nzrfoNDuiFVKPTrTNuM79dYO1pDC5P3Jw7QHxM5bbsfWDvuUIPxoDEJ3duAA8160Y3ZO61HuJy7fA3J/6jcpF6196nhqIVhkCIyBb47mZRn0anfUVAxOqFCqQTixV3nawC99kimGwW4CFR/gAu/Nj9YAIoO/gEDVXN7o7Z7/c886mp/Z6aG4HVEi4EobaH4e/5EeWj7oNVmwDKZoz9Oh2RoGT7rSUZMiVaKFw@7oR3oiRXpr9oXvEbtHixBpBPAnt3BVW8JTjNl1rcPl1mbhAohq2sYpOL3pIJ9I@eZfAvVcYJlHxtSofspSNthrau9zt8ALbqIT5OHfcZ2bv7oXqgM9Yr3KehcdH0P3M/cvpImIg@SokzehM13CuyfiPlYFBTHUDUEfN8ObAtygqZe8/GWHZ8OaW23JjCtsEGIswrEIIf1uMp2j0Rm2XzmEJsYCdXczIxf519vC92PQw1wyjJ6c9AXo18rrdbNYyEsxbqE2uYuuGwJ5nfVw7qm0vQgPUVvQyKnbx8xY32P966HfLMtli0Q5FAkuO06hL54gKvaUIPdHWTiq33@7XVcInO@XvkdbstNxi5BNlLst5PWaRaJBGn8smTDmVwp0S0tiKjRzdvv1bao62UjZViL7KmcqskBb2aMMfNDJBO4/AvzcXzjYfsCOsslEjpLzAArM7F2ww/mCqZ7bQ5DQyHAAT1iEp6mjb2N/u97JkV/YGOvG8MuNPOXf7Hhq27jTuk6705fO0V07JHk0zVo5zkpRDYGq62Cs6J30czwY7odk@xL3PUebkaIHdIXEP7a@3VePj9EkpkSS1GnF2y8Vh@Vf1DgPDbdggPyz4NM2l99wrNI4EtO4AM8A/3DOzpiiUm1U/mg0LRJJexEp2kHOA2uD63vy4AXNgz@/Oi@amnes27oku5fFolOWp6BnSGmv9SngTWzAGS248LPE4hwt@pHicdjOS6Tm2VijCo2AjNuGZWPtbJZdUaDwZjgr8L7vtFNOaK6j667o/Y/87G75EuMfsd5gsSJQ0rKV0WY3usTEIGc1HiU7ZsTxar0kIzHKZO2N31ALiptVDY041jH@clpTAdd2kvLgd7X63cKJRIOp2d2G0vm8zN/ctET1F39ERu2oTtmZ061sYiy/TUwvHnTngLAQA/VbX7b3u95QAeM0r4g7J9lSRih7st13G1wpbzigmAQqM6Mj8mAQFg8hNEjEmXA/00HxtxVTtZXbux@uXX@H46Tof/jSvoDsUO9bZT9orMWQPZdDTxcW/sEMuHUPtj11tC/NRXiaO3YsJz3iZIASH2orHoWs@MTa9NWmHisGCEgI5bX8uDC/HAq3i@9UbpnzuBv5qEBuGUULrc4JzGdgv1L4QRLupWok@bRDQrelOw0bTNuiNtqnDH5fzeCpm2FIQzHBQPauGr0aK7gCUFLQ4yXeN0Z1xbM80Z5AFbKYsqs22Ki@ze2nLzFqTbrE8e4tex3nQUtVqdzRhMjI8Lw@zafCmipYCo1Q6k3NyrfLdJ7EybXcvTwPEQQ7laNYjxbcDJEyFNyvQ87gRmp0MBwwz4dnO0uu0om7xc7JHbLZcdsaqz@jjTAPEibcQ1SdsUcY1DbIJv112uqP/CAkaSCsKU@jt3cSn6yMrulyGHMOsszFzZgNYRoTNlj2boSsBr3z50NkeAOGUZV16o3nAdD8h9261rT7bnPuUo/yADhiDLlndzCoGW1D0cMj9vrK4cjfq/PHSZsmmG2FtbXBh39PtQ/ZyXxNdKe9y4wvDEVOa7lRCCk7b9k31plv1eNW2MzqlRx9CxR3uiBPEyGbrWkTNX9cveJsUWvuKuvYCaKD1oQ20GoKh4h3R7ZyaUYuBE8wmhGn3INttm6yPBj9aIkF/jp7g3T9GGw@BwxbS2xTYKrLrvJXommfW2rDxvjahhmjYKr18iwWty03GnEr7CmqQ1FQTLz/UFolrgMk6rZyUj6powyIJbnkf33wfa19qHQ8OXUMT8yN1iB5z5YdGbi3Ihc@QvrtNJnCxb8utCt62/XpGKrwUcXJiyOqJ0GbF2LVvpMHX95hd/RpgZt34oTkZRpiTzKieARhOc3/aD/bGvjfm34eXmQx67mCzTCrBHFTIgqwbgfm2z72R39Ab5xBieKj98MIxaQsVdP8ZTMtk8xNJm2qUfno0nS8/uCpOLMwL0Qvk4G6uPUy7VIMU0rbj1jcdIYaV5sJmXeq9eojmGlKJm5n4fViIFaYVr88OEzBu2yYBZixzw1Z6A0oFUKl/VToiU2mej5BUQ7CaXJrBh3PTs4J1YiuU6VWaKMGiZYhWhPYP4R7Q1RdgBsCe/cl3cUafOYeHCh@qezA3XB8w66NBYTbhTMCjrqikD9GN1iEyUbcYxRv/eHOwIQe43m9Z@74/5/HYXdkJbk4XtO3BRQbgDTjVeE2A6qOGcsL0kx5pDb5BWNDYG48EN0ce2oE81nR@1INi04AMbYg9EEKhQ1g6cE3wRGo9/cT2NqkE8sXUZT6jZrMdUdVQta9h7G3CcE9IqtJWc93femeIbc@4rafj7v54fcHN1SX9H8dTEHzsB/@M22/bMrTbPRBRQrumuF7cCyf4NKIDQ/X9wxBwreCLUO4qBOdLK4lNyzwKvESpn0/yV0Vqjbr@y6a3jupvrmfmeLFACCa1LcvDzfFlu1dTqJnJ3TbyQVATym7pfIRgRgfTCP96S2ZGWGkk@xGhY3xF4zNMYfN1m0ymYHvGDK/SFt6QPcoo7sCCz4Jjk6hEhfeCu08g6WzfV7bbuM4R4PP66r4sz8tzMJxRQuVgFA4spMa0WJ/DJnp9moJsb4SyQu@ylRTYkMokYvze2VGSd65K5fVlkx2OWaRL1Rb0FAYaGsjeb6bvCM5aYG0IYfRtt2QpnmQ1EM2Z2J2LHdINKIE/zRzzGPcjcwYaRVpIU9vhI0QRTUTPIfeinOsm9cNefdUYQjR3NSfyNh0yghG6sdBjKczO1wOx@1Fg4M1quSYuldl2xxKinAbeE2Mp@IUmrMV15TYP2Ol5Q4exnCjGfrzzhyTdYl8Rxe3HdataPUqLBO/q9raTO888ZvmhuMAmwjSPEn4WhQp8eBGiP50Sqr7cxJD2uFjw/NAhfoZOwlZ8G2Ga8GCc32yMiBrCV69ms8MWTu6WkLhNuLn5@mxTy8v@L@HE6N9xqlJctiHSgv5vyHcatCsgt41zwV3PXEUHk3896i15y9M9zhoDHfluBB8NCnTK9dvMItsGnR4tNaSD/lOUfnMISoq55maPmFRsQnyLBuuZnK9RgG4Ji0OqDG6W5r4h7V7gF2S/g@D3lcOFXFdRNczOM4KZlt3ZIrWr0KWBZDURSMp3632sPwKlgjzLqS3T86oAukUlQJXU5IZk4EsFcm5CNEIAv/z7ycvpSkyvQ1iM2s/ywmTHhueVUziGrqZd2Nz3EAq6/X0VtdAQ1sQQZ56xrxGdFk2ALOluM4UbZjwWd3kh5@5W7Ryo4acJVmDiScPcfZYWkEUkZkYiZzYU4osLcMfVT0kBQG@qEdZKHS@lFoYmmTD45baUib7ill7f7nWi@UXug8yIy1OI/O3rNQ1Je/tcuGk7hV89TIXJQxsz2dovagA1dPGhVkKYPpD/xU@C69nnl0PhaZ8gt8aZA1aJ1XBnIVskWO3WaNJ0TzT8tubGBVRhoyxtc1RbMg5RYaRXu7hinb5w6IN5/wlSadd5hSdqviZ10rBY99shVFDPyOWmoTsMKkF/9sq3NXYiv8fCO5xdZog1Ttza15f59t23T1Blrl/hjkqxmfwR0mjEn@Hiv4WDY@lHBOkXnsj@ZVGdLTzyFHszzMk/QUDFE4zMwawOFYiEK@1XKOCDlpwpK8FKBKWe7ofBX7BkzuRvU2J3djt3HLn3bZ/wqZcdvexAE3sqiSvdhV0QHG6IhCcYPl303XK5H0sX81HJpRXuxEujxVx23db@@27/l0wlC6@M5KBHSZ8YYnTv7ka3u/0nywyLNewThOFNaJUF8aFht7wFnyFYBUudbv9nD8sw9HFXl3Epbvju2kddtIi43OtzLG/gZsdzRAsLUWXgWgXjehpjbqiVzef2UFiAUu7M36MFem4OtuH34HD7SRcsszez4p3FVc/gcrrU@fgv0n768Vr8tNt5eEVnAP6MjiBlCYLnSbUgFi2WD2PpuppycE433B2BLI9n7OMEt7gQ5LHstet2mch9PjGjw9EyhwW0Gzu6x20JXyRvhejv5uWCYBTxcYuMEtvytovxolWjMAqd5a9gFSLeg0xsohMQrB2HOAP13QsxdjG9LOwaSrhn6jEXU34V6dhlHW71eEBF33t9iY8pnK4IV7N3XF8POUg303W505PQSu1Xy7wQkpCz/S23SMZihQCoiH5vNH7ATtOWJdDQMsLtqEnsIEE9w@uhUWNTn2b6TFxxZcgOoG6ZV0MRSOvspE7b3Q8Gnt0q6ku7D4ETToudNAqFR4JQALtMV1Qm8wonLdq6s9jcTgAnsVnNyZjhvpDuym8zpKczBmwKuHu7ctxqC2YzPNMr8O@MfDkcbAogMoYokpKkzX02VaSHBMdi2V5NshuWo3NlCkv47X4glTOkWdTd2/OWVrTZ9LhdAXy7n9wxevaOnYKhkNxXEh2PU31TBielwmrShOlhYmGNUMtXGuHC6w8CwHuEYDPh2O1NOVAFGd69oiViccbyheC3LnPgIBPZHmamOK/Nhgyb1@TCufmts3xLe6IBqwVcpD1aAE4WPiHdqAGH7bVul1X0XW/r8IvRzRKrc4wRmkUyRggs3uii8FEpwLfwg@JbFe6jlZCXKsmnK@ZgNxNrUoDCoz/edBUuystEd69CY1fQG96mfE9o99UbfLRoo6r69HuTNiUj1n95hVO8713b0iu4bh8LDyRPUitfnhp/QY9F9rDtZeE7u4yRx21VDV71630iAzFiXybZNfcUmkqS0tUFSt48JAGlAOGoQuI1O4uU8L1POdrw4oPqZyQESe6rYVsB@KJwbXmFmZU63zaJdYy1@Gn66UmOQyjohKkmSyNbyKNdy6PViJ342g@laOpzVqWDSq9ojJRh4WSqfZk6szvBnZUpJ5BsPNHWE9Ah@zTZBvAecbrddUaChBudw6000vDjuuWu4zC4z8MBB3uFPL6GWKeG5kA6f45yuobp7tHK2O0s1Ggn34OyEtXStspgwXYoMJ0jJ8D15r114W3nHYmwaak1SMg42kWG8@MlnqfNzOZ7Ek@8gjUE/RZpHOn0tbBzL6VnNIcJvvkxMZhQzOToZDQiHU8hBMGy0IPJjjhunIYrDLS6DRTXbm2zBq7ZyB7wcbfRJepNf4KnccWmUusYnGi6vZfCQ5@5vrf6InHhDyYLQgs86PpLRP8@KqbpYpC6quYAdrrNtP@pdaF@c4UGNQ2lTK10tUQWOsKe76zE4tA9IaXWtwp6MGmwLZPTeNfrjga4uN3@tCC/qyRm9baswNHfTnMv/8pEk0oIR8CRSecmhZFRovFygHrQE0Z0MzTSYg/KbQ/LapQ9u98YonPcGDNpUgUWbG4BVNpZDCos3EbxFmeJ3qlQPGOAaZXZ6ifF1qnqnNmNper7fF0JbiK5tVfEORHPQUr1weG@gCrhiDtaCM1oGnUHFYtZ@Evg7sHEmW7x9vdYC86Pvs/3Wza6TtYdfSaBF@iYZSZmEMd7DTLnNjxhI4GXs2jOmOEuC544ON7L6N@9Hg1DSegmzgIZyLLYUr27W1BpACo6m/bm6fWxoif3Vin6la4ZecMO4vUvCiCF7uXFe@j9MCNa9ezoATUivKrxc3idKtefHF8Jc1q320GkgeG1@2UnLnK0Yw8y0Sd1wnQgucCJZF53th4oBut2ySlxHxrhJyAtfjkoIesN6PGCeUWfPrtW4EiTmYEiBdknzC4V4m6jnOrbVA9@xNpsvx262RTIlnB02r1d0qP@X6vS392cD5UL958pMqUUtu3h4wd8slmoBC8DG472TlTZFHSz59VLqTinMi0NTJct1ztnwrZ82ZTSmXQMxeS2AcO9KjnBUQX8XiZhtu3h2o@vHRSoo4f14IEs83ALDt7UJWZ0iNSRt8xhd13ldo0Z9iR20y8KCHZ9ej1mPioR1mZAo5BAJ@jHdyyTrhlXjLEIGwSEfQ8tE1xIPOKlKgy5XVJGO5hWOKIT9cnO1kP5mu@ITtr2HczWvuLDt@@Lt3uNygDnvrxGk3v5tkGRqI8TbrPjZkFQYimTS8/ZnY2zm67b5RRBBI0gq6cunX0aTUEWGYVIQQqTohhmgqWdSqtFHsPMD1gWIwArO3uz2kjkbchr7cUeUf7tr@jIpcUbpFPjnsH9DA@DFjGvjYdWD4/YGkh2vT87MlO9IwVZbk@bSGS@VQoZIzep0qPyegWHh7DcXTYdYj859ieAW9W5XqaQB@NKNk636hI1sYaH5M2lb2dLiBuvHFDSDoLjSOv2B65w7kfItejmB00I7JWql0iB0y3RwpQHy5F0m5CJqvyZVrf3UISREHEGD5uB2Bx0bOuPGUnu1grNwy482YzNSNuj3VOGYghyaro2PpA63WykQk0nszb3Dptom1VeV4mAX/XGtlXyRpndNLIl@pjU23XC3C2CazcAI7nessPAV8U@FgQ7HmxuDxuBjsfSlT0tANB7ITY3btUQY/B25vVOoleXrV@0StwN22F6Io5DWVRCjp@o7SVHP0xBy3RHDdfwbrM@MkNy2oEo0X2c1ERALZJMxNiuK9bQHTiXIi6PXpvXV6i/o6Iu6NZkpLCK0ME2PA96CfMUPO3MuzPJTBhKbtGY1r4K2ZZvLx8nj/Qi2UnIEgq6LQSDcG9vkdTbtr3sqqU5CvyRp3R7XhiLj6zIrf@GmP8vP4RC8Cer32Z24MDiCR1ADDasqKrfI8bcoJNC3TOWoqsGDcBjTJP/7sUVO5ERFuqV5bFujcamRwZ7S9j74DlrO5XojlNRZOKEYqMpQXxIyA3z936tTh1NIRXFi920xGmxaIXgobfIFO/fNsHK32LRvq2/JyOylVT@fqyZEnkLA3zaCp90aTrDm@azUDorpjp8QiPj7m4nbl@uIiJr4HGfs@bcMJfdQmKU86IGYSd3k3ZF12gZG9ZXDa0w8qk7WIwHIyZ7BgN/atSaf7i0G6ktGL99X2twbm@TYMzgpBgnW9RbE8XF0/VN2XW9gm5VwRPl/BY28haMW8uepiFoyEKwOBXbZXooP304PkiX0dbal9Bs45epbx87vZ372ljHzSaR0exCBOASrCYZytjcI4cuQMUDw/oiLaMEDAFUKsb@Fj1p0LcGk/ZjDXCoqRyARQvJ@pQIt3t0EA6oEQueiJmSRd0@R0fUsC0ebu6PCdt1uuDGl7HnVw50ZBJkuqTf/N0HMjo3thHGC6vIAbi3Aov7CYXDy2eWb4tY0uSybIpoDk2A9S7DUqfLPuLCNTYj/t62GgVwxbIxh4E3LQZj0CGldWp3rOAQhmVf/n519PlxD88f3rO4yao4oJ3CeLktV4bjELdTDOqDEtCGs8fLbrnJTuvn8HagaQhR1XLlE3ZBy3dzC@zWHiYBSNmO3IXowPXdoxhy60lbZC3AuTDMVLY1QF@cvKbIlcugrQDEmC6jC7QFTPTYLoh6xVpZT3e15LWbH0p6YyrolFAwGP6ochCQb5EVgCabu@mpajihmGYLNwc2eswn@JYDf6ItYUN44kdBTynuy@Jw0OEdQw1ju/CV89DHoIQ7FceQ/VL4QPeVdom1TC@fLQa4otmRxBpAj2IvVOGbqSp6BpV/7mjle12I76WiZ5hLfsdq8Kubzx0xUWE3oNeA1duD6EKgxyfvbkUN29N2kI1GjCy0txPBeJ23HZs@7tEyXtUvFykLe9QdtdwaAr8O9BiuDSe9eRu8xbDVcdWkih2j1aI58z70TvN1tdvuJ/oY2Nhg4NNCM8beVN1@uRpoUK6bruVaDd/cSiMkJlF/j3BkY2fe0UKr8UxzCQayArFGMEUlBFsbVRWkWMgXUvvYpkZmJsMnoMn4HNic7uAw@TYnFm/TECk2BjVaGWebILiljN3GCADJcdmYTBSr4XoaOgBaXsOFherZoozjglVrwxy82CyXSRAuPu62wj2PkoYABxzOzC7rVsJEV3UrtV6xYTZWSLCjZnjJzdvh3JW9YFy1eyD3nG8xqK8nmsOs9zrBZ@iR6iSBCoWeuOhPo73FcAflDIs@U6fubqdk12jmj7urmL/uHg@bUtuG1ptT0F9vz4917TDNFTHwI8DF93gEomsZibur0CecrCVIiO6amqJH0KAtKZufEB/aO9nW5Ra7ErQDtzlx@6FB9Kv/pggo44hulyk3DDCpT/v3fD1FYOQPY@LYhVqePXkRGk37LxS1awhdXnWD49cjD0WhQRMmtGcr@iK69@DIkVAsIqe0wx/LfgAuObiRGQI0pQrVBknsZBPnJM9vhZlqbMjDMS7Xw5rSijMTXHurl1kJ/CrKQMwDij5WJ5p2qeg@upy6nJddE5CoJoixbgDl9ILOakYs9Yb4EOXoBOBmEm64aq4JxT2HzZBJB@VEN1qIwdi@XF6c9rHKNjtI0UVeiuRiS1s/WJtEWGJv3mJY27y8LZj36C0uXFrvHlbhUaq2kW4PadMQHEOvaDm63/NmEe6q2F9BM0ROXoLiZBx6uFwAs1nQL/svLqLO/7Tki3iCbni5fJiLICPkLjqnNYooJdHT8BOYeAZ9yMVz2pVB1ihqrVjv2fda@cUddKPJj1Pk7yvd6Ura9jtmEhWJRwzlSKjhqorXvjFeNaHKtbNkkkUtUatm5obTrzeR6Dg6tq3ar90Ev/FKMJXTAmrCBXYirIEygUYlbXDaXHSrI6WyeSksuEVYO8NlU41sMZj7RCfibPcT/vUKiUKIgf2vaGfYYIe2e264cjTZeqedbNAqRH00m8UQLUStMa9WlJYA1C5WIabNKuEVavuo1TBJIaLIwJsrymW33cewb3y@eAHeRtXmHvNWRmNIZRH7@CJmrzZ0SjnI1uOOZXwWnm6u1Q3LwJZ1J/Hev62jb5d18MPXUxOiecXGdJnaYHRLiFVuWYxth5AQDO0fl4ppT9jzn7Z9BzvRLWXErT7YyHNcY6Pd4k6Vs14HM4xh7jX5Cono5eGUi/Ym1Z1kP86QuQ/uNm4@XLVneonFDwSMxfp2S5Aae3UUe9RUNESN3PRtPGFBAAL50VbJ6VtjW@38FXqSd4dNIRq1cquBUNEpNTrOLVoykT3lmG4YBUDmSDc2t7krN2zfNh8lTAFD@S6dOS5flNswR/iRS97CpH@zUU3TX4u6W41y@RIZ@9y85VbU3Tyc8oOJ7yd@XkqXrZ@uVg@dZ3Rml5MsME8naYqthSR5EbjzCWKVic8ZJDZS9XlF28lYKHKk4oZiHFi2r7UXFvSVGjYsbgRDgyTg1YCCgzwldNFKzmE77mKRRP5yYZZ@5DYDyGGs31AjVZhbnS6TmGmvSx7zWGZrdEu6uKr6bLWhboyFeR1W4jGUYAhhjrDCkN39mZEihIGegVHoLwtxcTQJi@YE2ayyxMlRsluLKy/iyHiZ3BsMdUISZ/2E0NGgMgij2mxePnSpKupH004b@4UhypAlVntMW/i6iTyseXSxdvK83DRIQ/nCUb2MR7vajVLYuK/ZA9hU/evQE@WfpxADA3eSYGrNKDmTu12P3gMV2K9jOFZASFUvRoCYJhBhDe8wXBGik0QOt5Ix8MZHGSOSDcy3l4nkENDX07bdRzaMKDSABQPOiADabQYb24StYb3vy2HO5RIEA@ZGW7j/scGW2SHe2NFhVUiJ6G/etm3@VBAKsAJNz/5cVM2Ft7GO5P7LzU07REP3MPFrL5O44r/cXg5hQwzXjIwbCjJD2@3@HOlk828aeh7PRUJHxLTXD8FF/9uuNNNHLkFqqbcnH3wAC7DFnfQXcpFLfHeYmsO9tpt@TNZ0o7qv1vmbNYBnQ5DhMGDufnXYtE8SqGmLiatM4tRZ3mBrGHV6mXBVgGoNb9YaLQ77@4kYayvfrc1h6U7aCd6efNXAbgZhAT4k09a5Rx2dzgLuQpN5bUDkxj4lccq4GBmiD1u0gii02i7A/WCLnT7bbYGTbN3L/kQKOcwkmxC63TV7gB@2BcnbwECx2QHmyK5Ib8ebk33WNWoQLjC8RtNTWyHCl@UYM1/A7yD/UPiVw40saPFg3fYk7@1ga3jS32aeWls18Cv6wcN1ds3KPEEMhgf88OI7lU3flxrYUU3Ck1Idc2q@HlpuriebkVED5Iz2zpmueBcLySZzzMA5k0FZkB4Xwdwa9YZ0xTLChHI43TYJ2e47UKgeU65XIPumJWXZzK9Q1r@DzpiLBQGmcmRjtQ0/SRv/hoE7UHA309kQK/XfpCrBeEpa9gmTl61LoIGNwWAMh3ibpNseqn8ll3mDujl9w2twOcMhLIX9S1BTK@3eyXJq9JGlommyajO7p71vz5AqTtpw24B9aw6KIeuOInWJ3C070qCbYgFVPocS3cte1y/Qdczelxa/XZHCJaU8ow@GIb7S@dv18vDsWncyhhRkSNOGqkpsKJTphCmwI4YKG3ckwR76XLdcdsEYrGS4xE7te2zix1FMaQGjD1th82ze0bPmR@NKycameYL9FmJeHGOsA81RaY5DYK9w45zmqjpGwZsezrp4TsoZdDTki2uw02v65TmWYnX1r9AUd1eGRT0OPpGbvHUXpqCSS8yEMsp24bUG49n6QFGboEpP88fCz8P8DPkKmx4ebWDbdaHrVpNXYsXXM11F3nDbG7FUTTWtuPq9opsbgUAMwT40C3s9Y0@rGEUtz3XGANX59Xm7jkZAJexGJTtcN2EsFVjm270HgRgWitrpHqslXAp1BO2Ix2jp2ehJhherPcPDAJKTwg5rRhlmfwYbYo9CZBJj5tNnHJK/L3NNvvfv9wt3HhM/pUc4UfTL3TKqJewVvBV2spU9NH8LTo6lOO4eub7CHBsit22Sp4ruPvNX@N@HNsH5Qr3BdXLcadK5PXsQndAj@OsJ2T8@1QvswG1QeIkLs00x6Hj8il2UONJBsBZ2J9EHIEhR79IbzuTdps6q/7SKECtaHwujU68EO6JWO1FIttIMxkT/TEN8IuOkR81oMWs3/FbCxUhBQulq/oqLt5vElho7ZLOSorI/TNtNmwK9vG0no/rgYHjXhmg2WwI/bVmN2VrDZrYQTHxc04y@cpWqEkW50EbZ3fq2W7Ssht2f4rijJqxCoO8IHijWsHhPfthy22F3I9FtxNhrBKvtXvWx6Us0u46xiEQqm6zHGiGaiYLVBAPQZ2iz27yLoAuhB9tuD5Cfy2NxzX0HljH5Yt6A7KAjJ6uhZfBgC78BcKgYS@5efptFP4NI3yjvP2PGDgnU8reoPNhPWyI0BSOf2CQq1P@iUNNNapuLGrRhKGBfOZr3CAhWTcwf29aNNXqqw9kq8xZwyAHBIPpti2qn0vz04wi1MT1IbVBafqjsruXOASHvMYslktk63LEeeQxgBLGhFQf0i6p2tKr247fmbNkO3Am2U@Ae1W9rN2wsp6Ibd9EsMOVLw0SaHKaGFse7vqcCIle7oS709GybqmUmgzFJKxic5kj9IDTUSBI3sLLxEHgTFKOOCn@jUApE9@XhdTmtFHDecT6KasY7eisY6Vg0Wg/1AOEOlu7JgqOFN3KCbapGXE4zXc5Zkmy/nkqoUkip9PbTxQh0p9iH33xFi41g2zU43Q3JvhzbhpuK2BYg08qe/7ZIs5iG3@mg5RbtNs4GzKwG6hJ7YzZPYhnwtZDzTIRFd@poR15NpamQTK24KMxv0cjB8ooTdx2pFW9Kd8@gtW6ttohJBGQuFFStpNgoE3mY/lQObAAjtM@U0OcVjQHyJePPK6YKY2yZCDp8Xm7Q5D5gO7qqmhiiVZXt@uJaAu2xbCdIB3C6X6XowF66Ly5uOCX7mYyA047O8N5J5ML2bCz/nCNeKzPe3QHR2tESi/ymuDVXCQ/X84gJTjHzEghmHg28sRbWcKVb1dUMEGwOObkI23E0z@AHVzGZ6XDoTjdgyR5TdG89av4eUrMSQMb6w1g4KYjFf8fg41fbgtRtuAB7B@zbTLAOsjpnE5t4dP1u94ooIN8RGzEVm9Pn6gZhgcIVNN5SEI35bBIN02gSrargidK@aikI2BLEfBVLBE9MVx28QRV3mNbxMrUGkTMRSEh2ixTe2hj3mCOTwN8BC7F3NLJttsxO0fjdmk9lNqG7JGEc76vlhLTS48dNUXHebGt7r8zhzlue1s5uYsREszhNHB/sHa8iFHc6nSqLpDSoCzKc3/QkaWYHaVXlara1HoJNqBupSbOzUbm6kmXzxY1PnurNBaTPCJ3ydjcnpY2Rdl2jOJSKGm0vu81ns@MQ125bimo1wC2fy/XrAgQADOJYoeF7OXmkmojYxrtTbg6XDFvqnzwuEw90A8YqMcfYx1S7j3emO@ieftgm3SFDna5F3rESoUkKKIjQj74JC76kKNI1misMDpCEXI16JqKlhG@bz3O7XZty@7SpLG7lZ/cOGCMZbyp0aXUG0XbAnjUoEz1Mw22Qh2jpw0C2u23cEV0KRxjtwQlhM3qZv5O5u/k2urLjv21zqByNZFFX51RoVlJ3B7rN9oi2cDTMTh09MGRm68tPHdAjOrp1t3dxCa@6fG1d9MCPFL9ghRYcR4QGryvb390cJpUofEqm2GRd3U6WWoRikmawxbGVHR/U6WAjFw8HKkpnw5aM1bXAgllq3lenbmqAQskyjNbQqM@ywRPlZInTAmUMcb6/Y/d82bjVDA685GYpOBJ4w6/D4jylWbNfIY03ipddKUHMcfX@1nqhSH@5/0amgAPTr0bCMMwJH0DO9Jc5efhCCe5@cm@z0jR8drwcXbbRqElWyPj8WoH4D4jn47kcrWqqDgO731wotLu/e2Iqpx/Ca6MgnxFmyicjW@w8TIsBkVw5/@A8jIl@XJaziXxSkTPmoxlF0lBDUhoc2EGcAx6TfzlmPz4fyjnPQTUwOzDiq0KDqotOP3D33gA6E/@QNS3K6j9aLlRTBqJVK66@fT@y6gxfMOR25GWswn7djuLUakBLya27ktNwbOnURWlG1wQ8ViJaHpf1DNYO3WZ5CsKmGXYxOzdd@RY4rZjPajvR8cAAK23ELechqbBPHEQDqg4TMq1g52PvLRqNOlAVJILcPfhKhKJKdOxUNixkdy@QFG3wwnkZICEG87cD4noGSR@jIvmMEaOBeLZ/caFBPZlrNQsE7Wzkvk7FQtVieSXUV8g5ahySXpEjuT81Pzf8a1St@XRUPLCiHp7@nkplDJ9il0OqoZajNg9t9kFWwfnsGcbEDBDapSPplMm3xWRjz1P7ynql44X@bBlcNsSHIFs9VGUkCNPdmyX7EIbjRn8DMhJ5RAnVOSGel0w4eCVL6ku3AgKWjt0ten8us0F5NAMp0b905O@epveVnFVCIzowu9tRp4AhB@phEY7dNBl/a80SUyuD@X2JTDaA1VnRU0crVK2lM0B4B7PZUjhbPYPB5/Zu9uOVaFDyDxc6Nmzhn@5eFzSJ6FSshqULQnr668qi247oppqiInkADOLoYUXXUdgNud/uh59@e8pFb8bPuP7nKVJrd5GgfiGzS5AZeOcnImcfLheNy@i2zndwt7XiVRH9Rs52H43ts2tTEsj3ui@hx6w2GxAJsHGDSm3YBRd1ery8UgTSwleZMq9wxZU1Cy54r@RVm8LgINmrsYfYo/j9gJQRGuAuX7VYTamiPSZOE3ME/WjcDkBd5AgfL7agNQfFTp@6J91KYvaVZYEzTqTQOjsSQgFyJmlgeQsXsjq1oYyr@Yazlh1xl4lfq18bLG@sNF4Zy@ZU2XpPTUnI7bDWk6eGuvImBGDAWMD79g98uZQNUFnMxzC1kAyAZRPOQiCnyhijelSrz2RXF22e@/T3o7UK@aHFsmrj9bpeLhaKfxwKDlte25TjuweCTNBtE/Byw@1G3PHdh2vauTM6HvnxDqNQK3i62wX7Te8mr@BiAcSsNs8Ph36VAExqELONEvsn3Y4DtICUfsFJuFsTxkAo6tM1cSGgf99kIL/caACCV/Hdyp6BpD9WHWL5iYtAv8u2oMzGaijjdkEQxiYBLEBXyTxf13HPCay3wmKXZ19g5Wf4HXvAxAUMsYoUpkBQtjLEfT@nCgRHtyYMgaYOyi/PzkBZFX2eMBiBgANn8zqyWt1aBjfcdR7k1lQ1H0u2@sN5Zd8C62NIHprfl@eq3abN4XD3rgpIU1yWcR010YlkoP1EXujNokN4qHayUpyxXE12cxcES3rSUUe0tgFCG5WtRMQmW/zLUQTGENbPisE3tKs0VS@tXBP3TZ9PcWaaib85y5Y20wELYvsz9vF5lNxbNsaUdBpye65Lt48NcmaPVXA6F@jOCS6vl9ddsJD4sSZ3ddUUNDROBXNKkgd3qICxnpVFY8BuVmnDSMvQWwHaI@srtzW6a/QGEhPEPcXN47IYm5eNrXajW@a5t7ZMM3Ar@8ssmdEqEeI392qpnTFKKQEFj@dKzVz484U03xZmM9rOi@MS19XwsezL0qHNngmvwkRQk1ZiEuZvv98WrlAgaNdLoEZnP@ZhhiixHkndsutz9L3iewhP9ubhWk@1P49O9ewmyNfcPnoGlsfL3j5IbIB3iFICcfi8HKECpSbQp2fIpSYa6thgvVzTObrQLT@JiTT2VaNL2HVEKBhG2uCJ/uEuQyKTyeZlX8WgnRhwDlgVcB8HtTQw43IKlmwik4zCOjcJuynn99RdHz99pu5qTzes19UugUTxUIZNoRz0VHf1KWEzU2DOCVHbKupuUAr7a9erGohQUM92NLyKSrxOWURTlQ/BsSmVG8PSZBOFlqO/AqW91F7OPiE0QfnB8HND6tKGNlTqt/rLsZIw8OZy/kAPpdJCRltrShzaQbK3ZI3BMo4k/XAl4gj2kY0IP0NipDHcaCZUG07@Flr3bHU2VMJsGkzc70QcibrLq7ndnolka8VcjtS@Ha97sHc2ZA7dx5yrm2rq1pDP6bwbECAsO2dfaTbHdkdw7NzztcsGvw6hX3YOAmmFNgY2/rcMqYXDNryHd/Q4O2lvkHjcxk8SKFWbDX5NiIPyB5H@ufRXuJoW99kduC5haGSXXHMeWvdeaVRAUXI3M2LZJFd51NLq0HEauopGP@VEV5RBsKiQbcK/vPw/JZnzu2QzWljz6nstygduk2zZxujX3nXCBdVTKfDZCIqGe1Bx03WLupvAUI2Jrh0FtA9iMjTeT71EFdNF/MmjrRQQfUQs4frY86W2bMPChvrNFHWJHu6wpmRyM58GhDDrZRN/rg8UfqxQ6VA9j2TxgY9jOBjuOgZV7baasFP29SQX7sHdbVcTnuG0BAdEG@dmvmT3zhA51LZI5HS3jlbs51iCYozsu5jtU7PtTl1nj6KPLcxAb8y2Oo9jV4SIKjX34Dlbm@4rlvs/m/rlhmM8nHWLwDi9bNs67ewWu@4gVJHQ5sgF3DYkalQt@hiG4PYeEstGhzs/u3@n51d9rmGvG7d9/CsMvMLFjZrO26wBnUzuFSNUlIXuRhj@VQvliCmb9jqyNMWnMQnGyuGUe0ndxWjrjpPg4bo08n21BsZ0pVFRNVkqsxG/HAt6l8pKISztN3mxcFke@bpApujQDH8tDNwSfNaWNqbdhUysRWOv6GcT7h0ud5/R7P6Xdm0tPiIl2B6e1N33n/Azs1O/7JySAW6kDJ2xp5jz6S3FdqgDkVKmVS8q4XC@y6awZpsRFbBIWXP4HthXQ5Fb9BLObnb1029@@@uv//z73/zx15VH4d8m6748oUao16sLsHXft2gwZbGD6d9v61RDhlw@4ldkhTnZBYqeNuIXJm@QASjUdS3vMbVCzLdHNHYSI8gGMOadCzbK0QOnQsRw9cgU2fuzCV8fN4ELC1sTitXHM9xZ@tsWMnQF2BdSqq7NmUhzNYmNEgVoTbKYKgGf77jBmSPAQh4MtM77mRJlUs/5K9vdGex7uHyHms9P2iZDtSnF@kZMtV6f21FguebQDH3YzxOEHkgdEGG02@EIlZB5Fih7dyyrT1iOpTK/Gc3RyRKv5IhN0yv6NaegGdri9f9t6kyyHMdhKLjXKfICrsdZ4v0v1kYEKPcyWXI505ZI4OMPbArBn/h@cFHi6CPtlCK@99KNfC6CW2l2EZHvPTaVp7vNhGojpNllZMqA6hcccMqEV55eBSjwll3vgpQRjIZ665yhhqjqfa3yM8gwP6VrJQarpg6PnHFBJ/noVfPHhw04REBkpehBFW3bZcmFQd2TmlYPqBBcxmaMoaywM/CPS4vPaYxzkar2lozxWCmQxmKEnwv0h91UYUxLuWfYp3yq4NHciYekXUZAEs6EtYIBX9WqVEA3xFripVVsM0qn51DwW3Le@rlMI70gmP5eWKyTBhyIPjM0SPlJfPEr1HSM9mbXqTZIY08gcxSeSja4JxsMan3noEiCWrfvPjbSXMRD4/thnzo/iVIxIQ3K@1EmDtjr9duphZ6OOrvqSMEnPz31C@VywbYos7Qrhb@YW1s4yRxKVdQIC0LygGmqi2XMziVPbNqUKjmmNJHpNHL/XiUluPfcI5ZMkIqmc8DorTWAQcVHr8Hyw5uZaQaBJy6cxEcOwVO5ohFF0nYms7hlnsg6TZqGu9fCi2Gpsks2HsT3SG/myUxzuNhUtmP3ntqmAKAj9lGnpa3nXvC5VzhF@Nn3EwEYLLep62XfKVKPmxAE87IxGXJN4pRshyPUjdqLRv6kYsTF0ReIt5Bx84/5WPhAVGnv/bU/Oqsd8m3GqJ1FeljKlP@tVcY1L181l4cknWrfPmMCeyUc9IobowRhi8ocQeaKhDE6XLr/MvQqsnSgvsw0MkBWU4zLxqY2xsiBjZVHBLcBsYX3fnwzSAUlOLW4r@mRJK5UXG2jtoc706s5CwGgKbgBovocBDbM@Y88fUG7sN1qUlRogpOUapzzXdW1wSKSW1KFZCgvqM7jyP7ev3fEvyWhFzXDfBdfk8ZIl//fYoppg1D3rrYToFDftX4iY3duFyT3ZiQdzbievjMFCjak333oahk6GU9YwwF0pJfhooFGl9o0Oe0ZW9JhoVaNK7MP@XFYPfaekA4/FdhQhxFcfsKM6U7qDufExDb/22wc05CW9lWZTC7DP9tvm9MJ36DaaDdMXAbmwTrhxBZ0svEUqORlnzRpYMBhuzwl/VUhmVJ1ElZWlrQW98HPfh3J4uwHx5zDwWrYpLaIdcM1N13rsYuJ4qFImCAE/Vz2g16iQfsWyz49NgyfdzQQd7/efnrRDqgOsv4Zq1Ks0BXsYyMRR/iVk4MsDwcUkkuujfaucWj0M/kcJn7Fg2ldmo4KqeXLcF5918PVNNKr6sInE6SkHONURs8CMHLmzUqBZavD9fVKNWm5NV2wm9rHCqY8p3zzCHOLu08u@q0t3E73AJNamEeTWHT0BJSg3eFjjG8YPq2k79HSS42uRh5kKqg5cXoIwZxBXMbwKy9qZkUvVD1paMecKnOYXCoS32g32wP@1Oi0M3sWIeRz4qw@WX9imavXQOMzBWCYx0ewwyobYrfxmyGuXB5bsb/MMJPp9ZXhdGZrsd53qFepbutLbOMFTCMSYCzUNCzDsRYp3H8pHcz/aMO9rMgeqrOX5gbMEA0qRRGLrirCZj4Ty9xDewhJktPI4fuvZjz07mnbf0JXZUK4Y979@J5iNw5tUDZLustmo/tY@iLYZe/mb2OWjVGXgXqmlleaUQrR47nkyC5pvykabz5rGkj/YJNuxFMj@FceBltj0x3ibAMfJdfQZhj64cVAQOdzINGn9ozDSHZHkthjNBx/uTPQNK9n252ilY7j47/P6/ox/g5g43s0F2bNN28d2OATeNblASD2CASwoAt0LVZjrlswn2/6CmV8dAswzOfYyh4IK3pFG3alw6nYJxeSKSQnj0JZpQLxcfZ3ZXR9eP6OlnZhdxyceFdMBG4g3K70kzuxzWy5Mi@sM5PoSZDpBp8@7yUwFeqev0vaMYNmxSBCpnPbGcn455gShzEZAEsS9uASkQZ5pnPlStULMUUrTbd1Ki1u6tj2Lkfa1JJOzS7TVhEIKrF5CavpNj7So8lcubTkUGNak8mTcVbUUdyrE51umnzcqV0f@xWhfYy11wThoTUibDM1sQEpXS1P2KDZccoZ0leNicaFYwDCe6k/rhTt1jO472zR2nBFyBg/K7aM3pSpx7u7YpS3BB6jB@HnOtLvfGWUdbrRY5kEISz9zNPTbqeHsD3wxyiYYTeLgh96WPQpEgbnTEKN7jVFFDOyl8lAmtnLB3JJ0PUzZfeFL9qlRZtpkjUJXpKvZa/4PDMM6CMn1zl8Wy6VkwMouxAXgowLBGGk0y0UBUbbjeyGuxyftz/GVgdH/LEIKJAKViy4k3DhWG9aRyGnuqfpBpuSMFziqKX7epUMxf7@DpRBgx90O2HxVO/m6Pp7B/wpjY9XM/E3OGVovM2AcR7jNb4HXRpOhvD4/Vvqqf0LpSTRbfb0FBHnM52sKsm4/cWeO/duRoBT@yD8gu6X@8Kuq20gWMMhAsmWHVuYbMsfLYmSEdglVlbTTkn@pb3gJqp1ipl14FPVzT2x6gLZWWdvzQYgBmSSNg/OQ70itBuDtsssGjOtubUyBCJ6/kvCFHhi1yZp260E0yQDX91VsOmtvE/DNz6kVrcnAajo/TfvOFFOk93oocMjQ@A3aWPB4Kr7X06CbMaLVtMQqJ@ZwVZEbZQ7Bcmikca2E8ycdxTzyvCSkcalQ6M04wKdXrymkSjWbsjXUNnjgSIiDa6zubAC1Om09VIwNuAQdjYNSYTOB1BxmTlzcmCeeOknUcBICKKS6baXnB58nDm9KOog5mzkEwkMqu1TCMv9Fi8AVzbVcj@Kira0nIFde8rG08S5HXofX01Li00SxBeVmFJf4Ykoa9NRQV0IYAmNl3qJyvt/jnkwdomN1ky/l9TeaPb13G6ZwAjVjzOw0igF9Qa@jJPheOUETojMDK21NJwGllHA8dH3ImTVTjm79rVModGBw5K55Q086owE5zVkmqqxvhf@Bw)

Comment: I believe you should consider the restrictions separated by one blank line to be for one function instead of considering each of them to be separated ones.

Comment: each batch of input is separated by an excess newline, you need to be able to interpret the function when given multiple values of it in different points

Comment: Also you can use the name `x` directly instead of stating that value when you want.

Comment: from what I understand and understood, every single of these makes a distinct equation, the challenge is understated and leaves too many loopholes.

Comment: I agree the question is unclear, but it's not a *loophole* I would say. You're supposed to treat every five equations to be restrictions on one function you generated.

Comment: where is this stated? `required values` bit may refer not to set of equations, but values themselves (a, b, z)

Comment: I think *where each batch of inputs (a different function) is separated by a newline.* on the score section. Also *example testcases* is also suggesting it. tbh I also didn't realize what's going on until I found the weird line breaks in the testcase.